# What should we do with ambiguous [sampling] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sampling) is ambiguous and even its excerpt says so:

> Creating samples from a well-specified population using a
>   probabilistic method and/or producing random numbers from a specified
>   distribution. As this tag is ambiguous, please consider
>   "survey-sampling" for the former and "monte-carlo" or "simulation" for
>   the latter.

In practice it is used both for survey sampling and for random generation and simulation.

We have alternative unambiguous [random-generation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-generation), [monte-carlo](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monte-carlo), and [simulation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation) tags. Maybe we should do something with it?

As for now, each time I see a question tagged [sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sampling) that relates to generating random values, I re-tag it to [random-generation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-generation), but I guess I miss lots of such questions. Another problem is that there are already >1500 questions tagged [sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sampling), so it would be very hard to manually change the tags and it would clutter the main page.

Comment: I am afraid with 1.5k questions in the [sampling] tag, we cannot do anything about it anymore.

Comment: By the way, a brief look at the tag suggests that there are many more meanings of [sampling]. E.g. I see it used for Gibbs sampling, for sampling distribution, and simply for anything about a sample.

Comment: @amoeba so basically, anything about statistics? ;)

Comment: If you take a sample of [sampling], how questions are split between [survey-sampling] and [simulation]? Because if it is something like 70-30%, then it is easier to do something with the 30% and synonymize/rename [sampling] to the 70% tag. Also, should [simulation] and [monte-carlo] be distinct tags (because even if there are differences between them, these differences may not being captured in the way users are tagging questions)?. So, perhaps a good approach is to start with minor tags, until the big one.